# PL/pgSQL: Select where in is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am currently using PL/pgSQL and I have a line of codes something like this:

```
 FOR r_var in    
 select distinct value as val, count(*) as count from table where value IN (input) GROUP BY value;
 LOOP
 --do something here
 END LOOP;
```

Input is from the user i.e. `$$'A123','B456','C789'$$`

I don't know why it wasn't working but if I manually put values instead of using the input, it is working.

UPDATE:

I discover where's the problem.

code must be:

```
FOR r_var in
EXECUTE 'select distinct value as val, count(*) as count from table where value IN ('||input||') GROUP BY value;
 LOOP
 --do something here
 END LOOP;
```

Comment: Is the $$ included in the SQL statement sent to the dbms? Which datatype does the column value have? (Isn't that a reserved word?!? I.e. needs to be delimited...)

Comment: I use $$ because of the input (i.e. 'A123','B456','C789'). The input must be a character varying.

Comment: You can't ask for help and at the same time withhold the actual function definition. That's not constructive. The function header is essential to the question. As is your version of Postgres.

Comment: Sorry if i'm not been able to explain my problem much. As i was saying in my question, the variable 'input' seems like not parse by plpgsql when i am using it in 'WHERE IN()'

Comment: The question is still useless without the complete function definition. Your "solution" is no good, that much is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function to accept a text `array`:

```
select * from my_function(array['A123','B456','C789']::text)
```

and use `= any` in the `where` clause:

```
where value = any (input)
```

In general loops are a bad solution.

As suggested by **@a_horse** in the comments it is possible to keep the function and just convert the string to `array`:

```
where value = any (string_to_array(input, ','))
```

Comment: Or use `string_to_array()` to keep the parameter type and convert it to an array in the function.

Answer (score -3):

Passing comma seperated input value in stored procedure can be done by -
1) Adding the values in temporary table and selecting the values in procedure

2) Calling a function to split the comma seperated values by creating table valued function to parse

you can refer to this site-
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6083/Passing-comma-delimited-parameter-to-stored-proced

Comment: That is a SQL Server issue. Postgresql can deal with arrays.